# Liunx based Azure PHP App service is missing MYSQL Driver

Tags: mysql, php, azure-web-apps

I'm trying to host WordPress website on Azure Linux App service.

I got this error:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

I searched everywhere but I didn't find how to install the MYSQL driver to Liunx based Azure PHP App service.

What I know that I have to do some changes to an `ini` file; But I don't know how.

Comment: You posted this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007774/liunx-based-azure-php-app-service-is-missing-mysql-driver and received an answer. It's a good answer, as far as I can tell. Did you do the `apt-get` / `yum` step recommended? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It isn't working. I don't know is it right to leave it in stackoverflow or to move it here? I got two flags there that the question is off topic!